# How to transform all the images from type .jpg & .png from the current directory to a video in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

How to transform all the images from type .jpg & .png from the current directory to a video in FFmpeg?

i have tried the following code and not working

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -start_number 1 -i images/%*.png -i ".$_FILES['files']['name']." -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 16k -shortest downloads/finalclip.mp4
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this :

- **framerate** = Set the frame rate for the video stream. It defaults to 25
- **-r** = set frame rate

  ```
   ffmpeg -framerate 10 -i images/%*.png -r 5 -y Path/To/File/test.mp4
  ```

Comment: This does not answer the question. You seem to be providing generic answers that do not address the specific issues of each particular question. The question is asking how to convert all jpg **and** png files in a directory into a video.

Comment: You want to convert all jpg/png image to video. and will remove all image in a directory?

Comment: I don't want to do anything, but CeylonDomainsSolutions, who asked the question wanted to, "transform all the images from type .jpg & .png from the current directory to a video". There is no mention of any file deletion.